# How to use iptables and ipset for destination host redirect to another server?

Tags: linux, iptables, ipset

How to block access to the list of the sites and show a notification page?

This example blocking without a page, work correctly:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set site src,dst -j DROP
```

I try to use the next rule for hosts redirect to another server with a page:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set redirectsites src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination ipaddr
```

Could you explain, what is wrong on the rule above?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use DNAT which is a target for the nat table in the filter table.

If you want to use the DNAT target, you will have to use `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING` instead of `iptables -I FORWARD`.

Comment: You mean: iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m set --match-set redirectsites src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination ipaddr but it doesn't work

Comment: Is your DNAT-ed traffic allowed by rules in FORWARDING chain?